# String as boolean in PHP

Tags: php

I read in previous questions about comparing string with integers can have unexpected behavior in PHP.

In this example, if $x is "2abc" it will print ok because $x will be considered as 2.

```php
<?php
if($x > 1){
  echo "ok";
}
```

My question is there a possible value for $x when $x is a string can print ok in this code? (except the empty string).

```php
<?php
if($x){
  echo "not ok";
}
else{
   echo "ok";
}
```

Comment: any value other that '0'

Comment: then it will be '0'

Comment: in case we are talking of strings only

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes it is true for one zero. but I tried '000' and '0abc' and it didn't work, is it possible to have long string and it print 'ok' ?

Comment: [Enjoy yourself](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)